# Calculate score based on weights and values for each ID

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe containing, for each ID, some pharmas and some measurements with some timestamps. I need to calculate a score in the following way:

- for each ID, between each timestamp starting from the first one, need to calculate the difference of time and the cumulative measurements between each timestamps, with some operations for each pharma
- sum all the measurements, for all the differences in timestamps, with all the pharmas each patient is taking (if a pharma is not taken, it sums 0)
- create a dataframe or a column with all the values for each ID

Now, my dataframe is similar to this:

```
ID        PHARMA       VALUE   WEIGHT      TIMESTAMP
12345      ph1         0.6       72     2017-02-13 20:54:00 
12345      ph1         0.9       72     2017-02-13 20:59:00 
12345      ph1         0.5       72     2017-02-13 21:54:00 
12345      ph1         0.2       72     2017-02-13 21:59:00 
12345      ph2         1         72     2017-02-13 20:54:00 
12345      ph2         3         72     2017-02-13 20:54:00 
67890      ph1         0.6       80     2017-03-13 20:54:00 
67890      ph2         0.9       80     2017-03-13 20:59:00 
98765      ph3         1         90     2017-04-13 20:54:00 
98765      ph4         3         90     2017-04-13 20:54:00
```

Now, a possible result would be: for patient 12345, for pharmas he's taking (pharma1 and pharma2) a result would be: 
for each value of each pharma:((value*1000)/(weight*timedelta)) -> ((0.6*1000)/(72*0))+(0.9*1000)/(72*5)+(0.5*1000)/(72*55)+(0.2*1000)/(72*5)+(1*1000)/(72*0)+(3*1000)/(72*5). The first value, division by 0, simply is a 0

How can I do that?
Thank you very much

EDIT:
The score is the sum of the measurements of each pharma (if any) at each timestamp: so, if I have 3 pharma measurements for the first patient, the score is: pharma1(value)+pharma2(value)+pharma3(value), for each timestamp

expected output:

```
ID        PHARMA       VALUE   WEIGHT      TIMESTAMP           PartialScore
12345      ph1         0.6       72     2017-02-13 20:54:00     0
12345      ph1         0.9       72     2017-02-13 20:59:00     2.5 
12345      ph1         0.5       72     2017-02-13 21:54:00     0.12
12345      ph1         0.2       72     2017-02-13 21:59:00     0.55
12345      ph2         1         72     2017-02-13 20:54:00     0
12345      ph2         3         72     2017-02-13 20:56:00     20.83
67890      ph1         0.6       80     2017-03-13 20:54:00     ...
67890      ph2         0.9       80     2017-03-13 20:59:00     ...
98765      ph3         1         90     2017-04-13 20:54:00     ...
98765      ph4         3         90     2017-04-13 20:54:00     ...
```

A final df would be:

```
ID         PartialScore               FinalScore
12345      0+0                           0
12345      2.5+20.83(pharma1+pharma2)    23.33
12345      0.12+0                        0.12
```

And so on, until each pharma for each patient is calculated in the final score, for each timedelta between timestamps.

In short: for each pharma, for each patient, the score partial is (value*1000)/(weight*delta minutes from prior timestamp). A finalScore, for each timedelta, is the sum of the partial of all pharmas.

I hope to be more clear now

Comment: It seems that it would imply a division by zero?

Comment: the first value (division by 0) implies a delta equals to 0, so the value so be calculated is zero

Comment: Can you add the expected output? The description is pretty hard to follow

Comment: Added a desired output and more clarifications

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by first dividing in type of pharmas, then, for each pharma given to each ID, calculated the differences between each value and the value[0] using this part:

```
pharma['Date_diff_cumsum'] = 
pharma.groupby('ID').Date.diff().dt.total_seconds() // 60.0
pharma['Value'] = pharma['Value'].apply(lambda x: xOperations)
pharma['Date_diff_cumsum'] = pharma['Date_diff_cumsum'].fillna(0)
pharma['weigth'] = pharma['ID'].map(weigth.set_index('ID')       
['Value']).fillna(0)
pharma['TempVal'] = (pharma['Value']/(pharma['Weigth'] * 
pharma['Date_diff_cumsum'])).fillna(0)
```

And summing all the TempVal for each timestamp for each ID